# PHP receives the data incorrectly when I send it from an IOS device using ionic

Tags: php, android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a problematic issue, I send data from my ionic app running on an android  device:

Data send from the app to the backend

[image]

I recieve this data on my php backend like this:

Data I recieve in the php backend from an android device

[image]

This data is sent and recieved ok, but, I got an issue when I recieve the same data from an ios device, I recieve the data like this:

Data I recieve in the php backend from an ios device

[image]

Have you got any solutions to this problem? how can I manage this data? can I transform this data to another format to use it?

Thanks :)

**EDIT:**

Code in my ionic app:

```
 var camposRequeridos={IDVisita: this.reparto.IDVisita, Expedicion: this.albaranes}; //this.albaranes is an array with 1 or more objects

 this.communicate.postRecogida(camposRequeridos);
```

Code in comunicate.ts

```
export class CommunicateProvider {
  private defaultHeaders = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};

  constructor(public http:HTTP,
            private auth: AuthProvider) {
    this.http.setDataSerializer('json');
  }

  get(URL, params, headers){
    let signedHeaders = this.auth.signRequest(headers);
    return this.http.get(URL, params, signedHeaders);
  }

  post(URL, params, headers){
    let signedHeaders = this.auth.signRequest(headers);
    return this.http.post(URL, params, signedHeaders);
  }

   postRecogida(camposRequeridos){
     return this.http.post(SERVER_URL + '/Recogida', camposRequeridos, this.auth.signRequest(this.defaultHeaders));
   }
}
```

In the api-call.php in case that the method is post:

```
case 'POST':
        {
            parse_str($var, $POST);
            $_POST = array_merge((array)$_POST, (array)$POST);
            break;
        }
```

And in recogida.php i transforn the data if i recieve a string:

```
if(isset($_POST['Expedicion'])){
   if(is_string($_POST['Expedicion'])){
      $expediciones = json_decode($_POST['Expedicion'], true);
   }else{
      $expediciones = $_POST['Expedicion'];
   }
}else{
   $expediciones = array();
}
```

**EDIT:**

After a lot of searching I discover that is an ionic bug or something like that because I try to build the app again in ios and on android and the issue dissapear, but sometimes appears again when I build the app again, I dont know why this is happening

Comment: I suggest you send the data as JSON

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You showing us just a few screenshots of what data supposedly looks like, is not really helpful in figuring out what the problem/cause might be. Show us at least your code that gathers and sends this data.

Comment: Code is preferred as text not image. Thanks.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I´m sedding it as a JSON already

Comment: @misorude I updated the Question fo put some of my code :)

Comment: @misorude the $var variable take the info from the android and ios device, and that info is correct in android but wrong in ios, the other things are irrelevant

Comment: I can’t see this making much sense, you specify what you are sending JSON via the request headers, but then you use `parse_str` (which does not decode JSON, but data send as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) …?

Comment: @misorude After a lot of searching I discover that is an ionic bug or something like that because I try to build the app again in ios and on android and the issue dissapear, but sometimes appears again when I build the app again, I dont know why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

In order to give a better answer as to why this is happening (and how to "fix it"), the code that originates that data would be needed.
another question relevant to answering this properly is if the iOS data is consistent (always same structure). 
That said, what can be done is some simple data management/cleaning;
Create a function that processes the data coming from devices and enforces the arbitrary datastructure you need.
There are multiple ways of doing this, one would be to have a template of the datastructure, and the look for the values recursively in the data received. this would work even if the structure of the data changes, though not if the keys change.
I would advise to do some research before posting a question.

Comment: Hi Manuel, thanks for answer, the code that send the data is:
              var camposRequeridos={IDVisita: this.reparto.IDVisita, Expedicion: this.albaranes};
  
              this.communicate.postRecogida(camposRequeridos);